# Symfony2 script that runs from command line or web?

Tags: symfony

I'm learning the Symfony2 framework and was wondering if there was a way to create scripts that can be run from the command line OR the web front controller.  I know this is unusual, but there are some special cases where I like to develop a script with web output, and then run it later using the command line with no output.  My first thought would be to create a controller that is called by a route and also used in a Command object.  Is that the best way to design it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract your logic to a service, a class.

```
class DoSomethingAwesome
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function actuallyDoSomethingAwesome($param)
    {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

then define a service:

```
<service id="awesome.service" class="DoSomethingAwesome">
    <argument id="logger" type="service" />
</service>
```

And then, inject your service in your command and controller, or if you use a naive and default implementation get it directly from the container:

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
     public function someAction()
     {
          $this->get('awesome.service')->actuallyDoSomethingAwesome();
     }
}

class SomeCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
     protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
     {
          $this->container->get('awesome.service')->actuallyDoSomethingAwesome();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to implement your business logic in a Service, create a Controller action which runs it and also create a ContainerAwareCommand which runs it too. Pretty straight-forward :)